# Angular 4- How to bind property to * directive

Tags: angular, angular-template

I've build a 'accessLevel' directive in angular 4 that works like *ngIf but on different levels of permissions.

```typescript
@Directive({
  selector: '[accessLevel]'
})
export class AccessLevelDirective {
  private levelToPredicateMapper: {[id: string] : () => Observable<boolean>} = {};
  private isAuthorized: boolean;

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private readonly credentialsStorage: CredentialsStorageService,
    private readonly authentication: AuthenticationService) {

    this.createAccessLevelToPredicatesMapper();
  }

  @Input() set accessLevel(level: string) {
    if (level == null) {
      return;
    }

    let hasAccessLevelFunc = this.levelToPredicateMapper[level];
    if (hasAccessLevelFunc == null) {
        this.viewContainer.clear();
        return;
    }

    hasAccessLevelFunc().subscribe(hasAccessLevel => {
      this.buildOrDestroyView(hasAccessLevel);
    })
  }

  @Input() set roles(roles: [string]) {
     this.authentication.isAuthenticated()
      .subscribe(isAuthenticated => {

        let isValidRolesArray = roles != null && Array.isArray(roles) && roles.length > 0;
        let isUserHasOneOfTheRoles = isAuthenticated && 
            isValidRolesArray && 
            this.credentialsStorage.get() &&
            some(this.credentialsStorage.get().roles , role => roles.indexOf(role) > -1);
        this.buildOrDestroyView(isUserHasOneOfTheRoles);
      })
  }

  private buildOrDestroyView(isAuthorized: boolean) {
    let isStateChanged = isAuthorized !== this.isAuthorized;
    if (!isStateChanged) return;
    this.isAuthorized = isAuthorized;

    if (isAuthorized) {
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    } else {
      this.viewContainer.clear();
    }
  }

  private createAccessLevelToPredicatesMapper() {
    this.levelToPredicateMapper['all'] = () => Observable.of(true);
    this.levelToPredicateMapper['guest'] = () => this.authentication.isAuthenticated().map(isAuth => !isAuth);
    this.levelToPredicateMapper['authenticated'] = () => this.authentication.isAuthenticated()
  }
}
```

My problem is when I use it inside the html . in order to bind to the role property I need to wrap the element with ng-template.

```html
<!--Without [roles]-->
<a class="nav-item nav-link text-uppercase" *accessLevel="'authenticated'">
  ...         
</a>
<!--with [roles]-->
<ng-template accessLevel [roles]="['admin']">
  ...
</ng-template>
```

Is there a way I can bind the roles without the need to wrap the element with ng-template?

Answer (score 1):

When the input name is the same as the selector

```
<input *accessLevel="['admin']" ...
```

should work

otherwise the input needs to be

```
@Input() set accessLevelRoles(roles: [string]) {
```

then

```
<input *accessLevel="roles:['admin']" ...
```

should work.

Comment: Seems `*accessLevel="roles:['admin']"` won't wrong. `*accessLevel="something; roles:['admin']"`

Comment: Right, I run into something like that already myself a while ago.

Comment: `*accessLevel="0, roles:['admin']"` or `*accessLevel="'authenticated', roles:['admin']"`